# Pandoc .md to .docx - how do you get lot and lof?

Tags: pandoc

How do you convert markdown file to doc/docx with "list of figures" and "list of tables"? And the case is slightly trickier as I have some latex tags in the md file as I have to match some specs enforced by the college.

With conversion to pdf I have it figured out - I have `toc: True` added  in the frontmatter, and at the end of document I've added:

```
\hypertarget{lof}{
\listoffigures\label{lof}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Spis rysunków}

\pagebreak

\hypertarget{lot}{
\listoftables\label{lot}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Spis tablic}
```

- I couldn't add it "normally" (in frontmatter) as I would get lof/lot in the beggining of the document.

I've tried converting to tex then to docx:

```
pandoc --citeproc test.md -o test.tex
pandoc test.tex -o test.docx
```

But that didn't work. Actually that gave me much worse result than straight md to docx. Not only I didn't get lof and lot, but the tables with captions were totally messed up (also longer regular captions in footer were broken across several pages)  and I didn't get the title and table of contents.

Any ideas howto approach such conversion?